# Auto Namespace in Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Pro and Resharper 8.2

When I type in a line like:

```
List<int> MyList;
```

I get an namespace automatically added.  Unfortunately, the namespace it automatically adds is often wrong.  It adds Boo.lang which contains a List definition, and I don't want that namespace, I want System.Collections.Generic.

I have looked, but cannot figure out the setting automatically adds a namespace.  I cannot see where or what it is called in VS2013 or Resharper.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent an inquiry to Jetbrains and the problem is in Resharper.  This is what the support engineer explained .. and this fixes my issue.

"When you type "List" - what items exist in IntelliSense? I guess there will be something like "List<> (in Boo.Lang.List)" and then you complete it, ReSharper will add the reference to resolve an added symbol.

So, you may exclude import items from IntelliSense popup - please untick ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | Completion Behavior | Show import items in | Automatic completion."

Answer (score 0):

Try update resharper :)

Resharper v. 10 will show this case:

[image]

And, after Alt+Enter pressing, this: (you can chose right way)

[image]

Comment: I do get that option now, what I am trying to prevent is the automatic setting of the namespace.  But I will send an inquiry to Jetbrains to find out if the problem is because of resharper 8.x or a visual studio problem.